# How can i get the print values in python script in php variables in php script?

Tags: php, python, exec

I have a python script which do some processing over images and gives me text, the script is running fine in the console. Now i want to display the same text by using php in a browser.

When i use the below code, i get the proper values in php variables $f and $v when i exectute the code from console but when i execute the code from browser i don't get any value in php variables

```
   exec('python /var/www/abc/abc.py', $f, $v);
   echo $f;
   echo $retval;
```

In python script: I have something like this

```
  code...
  code...
  ......
  #in the end
  print text
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

How can i get the print values in python script in my php variables??

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `$f` is an array before calling `exec()`, then `print_r($f)` should do the trick

Comment: yeah its an array, and its always prints as blank

Comment: Thanks, that was what was wrong for me.  Forgot to make an array before calling.